# Integral type error when adding float to integer

Tags: c, type-mismatch, msp430

I'm working on implementing circle drawing graphics on an embedded device using C. I've precalculated the trig lookup tables for sin and cos and stored them as const float arrays. The IDE I'm using(Code Composer Studio for the MSP430) throws an error anytime I try to add a value from one of the lookup arrays to the `newX` or `newY` variables.
The error message states: `"../main.c", line 61: error #31: expression must have integral type` which corresponds to this line: `newX = (int) (newX + cosTable[i]);`

Full code:

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include "OLED.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "graphics.h"
void graphics_circle(int x, int y, int radius);
void main(void) {

    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; // Stop WDT

    init();
    Delay_ms(1000);
    graphics_circle(32, 32, 16);

    while(1)
    {

    }


}

const float sinTable[] = {0.0, 0.018, 0.035, 0.053, 0.07, 0.088, 0.105, 0.122, 0.14, 0.157, 0.174, 0.191, 0.208, 0.225, 0.242, 0.259, 0.276, 0.293, 0.31, 0.326, 0.343, 0.359, 0.375, 0.391, 0.407, 0.423, 0.439, 0.454, 0.47, 0.485, 0.5, 0.516, 0.53, 0.545, 0.56, 0.574, 0.588, 0.602, 0.616, 0.63, 0.643, 0.657, 0.67, 0.682, 0.695, 0.708, 0.72, 0.732, 0.744, 0.755, 0.767, 0.778, 0.789, 0.799, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.839, 0.849, 0.858, 0.867, 0.875, 0.883, 0.892, 0.899, 0.907, 0.914, 0.921, 0.928, 0.934, 0.94, 0.946, 0.952, 0.957, 0.962, 0.966, 0.971, 0.975, 0.979, 0.982, 0.985, 0.988, 0.991, 0.993, 0.995, 0.997, 0.998, 0.999, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.999, 0.998, 0.997, 0.995, 0.993, 0.991, 0.988, 0.985, 0.982, 0.979, 0.975, 0.971, 0.966, 0.962, 0.957, 0.952, 0.946, 0.94, 0.934, 0.928, 0.921, 0.914, 0.907, 0.899, 0.892, 0.883, 0.875, 0.867, 0.858, 0.849, 0.839, 0.83, 0.82, 0.81, 0.799, 0.789, 0.778, 0.767, 0.755, 0.744, 0.732, 0.72, 0.708, 0.695, 0.682, 0.67, 0.657, 0.643, 0.63, 0.616, 0.602, 0.588, 0.574, 0.56, 0.545, 0.53, 0.516, 0.5, 0.485, 0.47, 0.454, 0.439, 0.423, 0.407, 0.391, 0.375, 0.359, 0.343, 0.326, 0.31, 0.293, 0.276, 0.259, 0.242, 0.225, 0.208, 0.191, 0.174, 0.157, 0.14, 0.122, 0.105, 0.088, 0.07, 0.053, 0.035, 0.018, 0.001, -0.017, -0.034, -0.052, -0.069, -0.087, -0.104, -0.121, -0.139, -0.156, -0.173, -0.19, -0.207, -0.224, -0.241, -0.258, -0.275, -0.292, -0.309, -0.325, -0.342, -0.358, -0.374, -0.39, -0.406, -0.422, -0.438, -0.453, -0.469, -0.484, -0.5, -0.515, -0.529, -0.544, -0.559, -0.573, -0.587, -0.601, -0.615, -0.629, -0.642, -0.656, -0.669, -0.681, -0.694, -0.707, -0.719, -0.731, -0.743, -0.754, -0.766, -0.777, -0.788, -0.798, -0.809, -0.819, -0.829, -0.838, -0.848, -0.857, -0.866, -0.874, -0.882, -0.891, -0.898, -0.906, -0.913, -0.92, -0.927, -0.933, -0.939, -0.945, -0.951, -0.956, -0.961, -0.965, -0.97, -0.974, -0.978, -0.981, -0.984, -0.987, -0.99, -0.992, -0.994, -0.996, -0.997, -0.998, -0.999, -0.999, -1.0, -0.999, -0.999, -0.998, -0.997, -0.996, -0.994, -0.992, -0.99, -0.987, -0.984, -0.981, -0.978, -0.974, -0.97, -0.965, -0.961, -0.956, -0.951, -0.945, -0.939, -0.933, -0.927, -0.92, -0.913, -0.906, -0.898, -0.891, -0.882, -0.874, -0.866, -0.857, -0.848, -0.838, -0.829, -0.819, -0.809, -0.798, -0.788, -0.777, -0.766, -0.754, -0.743, -0.731, -0.719, -0.707, -0.694, -0.681, -0.669, -0.656, -0.642, -0.629, -0.615, -0.601, -0.587, -0.573, -0.559, -0.544, -0.529, -0.515, -0.5, -0.484, -0.469, -0.453, -0.438, -0.422, -0.406, -0.39, -0.374, -0.358, -0.342, -0.325, -0.309, -0.292, -0.275, -0.258, -0.241, -0.224, -0.207, -0.19, -0.173, -0.156, -0.139, -0.121, -0.104, -0.087, -0.069, -0.052, -0.034, -0.017, -0.0, };
const float cosTable[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.999, 0.998, 0.997, 0.995, 0.993, 0.991, 0.988, 0.985, 0.982, 0.979, 0.975, 0.971, 0.966, 0.962, 0.957, 0.952, 0.946, 0.94, 0.934, 0.928, 0.921, 0.914, 0.907, 0.899, 0.892, 0.883, 0.875, 0.867, 0.858, 0.849, 0.839, 0.83, 0.82, 0.81, 0.799, 0.789, 0.778, 0.767, 0.755, 0.744, 0.732, 0.72, 0.708, 0.695, 0.682, 0.67, 0.657, 0.643, 0.63, 0.616, 0.602, 0.588, 0.574, 0.56, 0.545, 0.53, 0.516, 0.501, 0.485, 0.47, 0.454, 0.439, 0.423, 0.407, 0.391, 0.375, 0.359, 0.343, 0.326, 0.31, 0.293, 0.276, 0.259, 0.242, 0.225, 0.208, 0.191, 0.174, 0.157, 0.14, 0.122, 0.105, 0.088, 0.07, 0.053, 0.035, 0.018, 0.001, -0.017, -0.034, -0.052, -0.069, -0.087, -0.104, -0.121, -0.139, -0.156, -0.173, -0.19, -0.207, -0.224, -0.241, -0.258, -0.275, -0.292, -0.309, -0.325, -0.342, -0.358, -0.374, -0.39, -0.406, -0.422, -0.438, -0.453, -0.469, -0.484, -0.499, -0.515, -0.529, -0.544, -0.559, -0.573, -0.587, -0.601, -0.615, -0.629, -0.642, -0.656, -0.669, -0.681, -0.694, -0.707, -0.719, -0.731, -0.743, -0.754, -0.766, -0.777, -0.788, -0.798, -0.809, -0.819, -0.829, -0.838, -0.848, -0.857, -0.866, -0.874, -0.882, -0.891, -0.898, -0.906, -0.913, -0.92, -0.927, -0.933, -0.939, -0.945, -0.951, -0.956, -0.961, -0.965, -0.97, -0.974, -0.978, -0.981, -0.984, -0.987, -0.99, -0.992, -0.994, -0.996, -0.997, -0.998, -0.999, -0.999, -1.0, -0.999, -0.999, -0.998, -0.997, -0.996, -0.994, -0.992, -0.99, -0.987, -0.984, -0.981, -0.978, -0.974, -0.97, -0.965, -0.961, -0.956, -0.951, -0.945, -0.939, -0.933, -0.927, -0.92, -0.913, -0.906, -0.898, -0.891, -0.882, -0.874, -0.866, -0.857, -0.848, -0.838, -0.829, -0.819, -0.809, -0.798, -0.788, -0.777, -0.766, -0.754, -0.743, -0.731, -0.719, -0.707, -0.694, -0.681, -0.669, -0.656, -0.642, -0.629, -0.615, -0.601, -0.587, -0.573, -0.559, -0.544, -0.529, -0.515, -0.5, -0.484, -0.469, -0.453, -0.438, -0.422, -0.406, -0.39, -0.374, -0.358, -0.342, -0.325, -0.309, -0.292, -0.275, -0.258, -0.241, -0.224, -0.207, -0.19, -0.173, -0.156, -0.139, -0.121, -0.104, -0.087, -0.069, -0.052, -0.034, -0.017, -0.0, 0.018, 0.035, 0.053, 0.07, 0.088, 0.105, 0.122, 0.14, 0.157, 0.174, 0.191, 0.208, 0.225, 0.242, 0.259, 0.276, 0.293, 0.31, 0.326, 0.343, 0.359, 0.375, 0.391, 0.407, 0.423, 0.439, 0.454, 0.47, 0.485, 0.501, 0.516, 0.53, 0.545, 0.56, 0.574, 0.588, 0.602, 0.616, 0.63, 0.643, 0.657, 0.67, 0.682, 0.695, 0.708, 0.72, 0.732, 0.744, 0.755, 0.767, 0.778, 0.789, 0.799, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.839, 0.849, 0.858, 0.867, 0.875, 0.883, 0.892, 0.899, 0.907, 0.914, 0.921, 0.928, 0.934, 0.94, 0.946, 0.952, 0.957, 0.962, 0.966, 0.971, 0.975, 0.979, 0.982, 0.985, 0.988, 0.991, 0.993, 0.995, 0.997, 0.998, 0.999, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, };

void graphics_init(){
    OLED_Init();
}
void graphics_circle(int x, int y, int radius){
    float i = 0;
    int newX = 0;
    int newY = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 360; i+=1){
        newX = x;
        newX = (int) (newX + cosTable[i]);
        //newX = x + (int)cosTable[i];//*radius);
        //newY = y + (int)sinTable[i];//*radius);
        OLED_DrawPoint(newX, newY, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how you draw circles on integer-only devices. Check [Bresenham's Circle Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/). Meanwhile, you do not use the `radius` in your function. Not that it matters in this case...

Comment: I've been paring down the equation just to try and compile without errors, then I'll incorporate radius. I'll look into that algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the obvious algorithmic problem,

You're using `float` as array indexing.

Use integral value. Say, `int i = 0;`